# .htaccess redirect to change parameter value

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to change the URL

```
/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=4
```

to

```
/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=141&products_id=302
```

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^products_id=4$ products_id=302
```

but that doesn't seem to match.

My `.htaccess` file currently contains

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^products_id=302$ products_id=4 [L,R=301]
```

It would seem like I could use something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)products_id=4(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%1products_id=302%3 [L,R=301]
```

but that doesn't work reliably.  (If I click on a link, it doesn't work, but if I enter that URL in the address bar, it does.)

Comment: That's because you have it backwards. Should be `RewriteRule ^products_id=302$ products_id=4`

Comment: Did you put `[L,R=301]` after the rule?

Comment: Post all relevant rewrite options you have in .htaccess

Comment: You also need `Options +FollowSymLinks` otherwise mod_rewrite won't work.

Comment: @ScottWilson Is it just this one `products_id=4` to be redirected to `products_id=302` or do you have many of them to deal with?

Comment: The unreliability of clicking on links with the rewriterule you attempted (which looks correct) could be due to your browser caching a previous 301 redirect. They tend to aggressively cache redirects. Test this out in a different browser or private/incognito browsing window. That's always essential when debugging redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?main_page=([^&]+)&cPath=1&products_id=4\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?main_page=%1&cPath=141&products_id=302 [L,R]
```